# writing an if, elseif; block in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

Ive got the following statement in excel :

`=IF(OR(L744=0, N744>0), "price ?", "")`

I want to update it to be :

`IF(OR(L744=0, N744>0), "price ?", "") ELSEIF(NOT(ISBLANK(P744), "")`

But it seems excel dosnt have an ELSEIF block. Any ideas whats the most semantic way of writing this in excel ?

Comment: Put an `IF` formula in the false parameter to emulate an else if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like `IF(condition, xx, IF(condition2, yy, zz))`.

An `IF` in Excel is a function call, and hereby you are nesting the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing:

`=IF(OR(A1=0,A2=0),"c",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A3)),"a","b"))`

I do not have this Excel version here. :)

Comment: @pnuts - because the OP wants two conditions?

Comment: @pnuts - ok, fixed.